# How to approximate several variable irreducible functions to reducible

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

$f:\{-1,1\}^n \rightarrow R$ with $f(x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots,x_n)$ is any $d$ degree polynomial and irreducible then how to approximate $f$ to $g$ such that $g$ is reducible with distance between $f$ and $g$ is less.
if it is not possible solution for at least $2$ degree polynomials.

Comment: Are you sure this is a *Mathematica* question and not a math question?

Comment: "with distance between $f$ and $g$ is less." What does that mean? Less than *what*?